# Why are the sprites in my AssetBundles ending up as Texture2Ds instead of Sprites?

Tags: unity

I packed some sprites into an AssetBundle and uploaded it to my server. The sprites are set to type `Advanced`, so I can check the `read/write enabled` box.

When my game downloads it I want to initialize a sprite:

```
Sprite sprite = (Sprite)Instantiate(bundle.LoadAsset("1.png"));
```

This is not possible because apparently the asset is not a sprite (but it is...) - it seems like, for some reason, the asset is a `Texture2D` object rather than a `Sprite` one (why?). So I have to do something like this:

```
Texture2D tex = ((Texture2D)Instantiate(bundle.LoadAsset("1.png")));
Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(tex,new Rect(0,0,tex.width,tex.height));
```

And that's fine. But I have the feeling this is not how it's supposed to be: why is my asset a `Texture2D` and not a `Sprite` already? Why do I need to create a brand new `Sprite`?

Answer (score 2):

Ancient question, but here's the answer: you need to pass an extra type parameter:

`var sprite = bundle.LoadAsset("1.png", typeof(Sprite));`

I believe that should make sure that any rect / pivot information defined in the sprite asset itself should be retained too.